# How to define multiple patterns in multiline

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want my logstash filter configuration to show Soap message and Exception stack trace. I am  able to make them work individually but not together.

Can anyone let me know if it is feasible or I am doing any mistake in below code ?

```
filter { 
    ## 1. To show stacktrace  
    multiline { 
           type => "myLog"  
       pattern => "(^.+Exception: .+)|(^\s+at .+)|(^\s+... \d+ more)|(^\s*Caused by:.+)"
       what => "previous"
  }

## 2.  To show the complete SOAP Sales with request/response.    
 ## multiline { 
    ##  type => "myLog" 
    ##  pattern => "<MySalesDetails"
    ##  negate => true 
    ##  what => "previous" 
    ## } 
##   multiline { 
    ##  type => "myLog" 
    ##  pattern => "<MySalesResponse" 
    ##  negate => true 
    ##  what => "previous" 
 ## }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in regular expressions but I believe you could combine all your patterns into one.

Comment: why the downvote? All _type_ and _what_ are the same you just have to combine the pattern with a NOR, which is very unlikely not possible with a regex..